# What's the best clipboard manager that doesn't need the panel?

Tags: software-recommendation, clipboard-manager

I'm looking for a clipboard manager that doesn't need the panel to be useful. Something that can be triggered another way. Or... If someone can provide an easy way to trigger the dropdown that would normally occur with a clipboard manager had if I didn't have the panel hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glipper can be called with a keystroke combination, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> by default, but you can change it in the settings. It will pop up with your clipboard contents and settings menu and doesn't need the panel at all, though it does have a panel icon.

Answer (score 0):

[Keepboard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepboard/) is another one that offers such features.